# How to send temperature data from arduino to my app via a wifi module (esp8266)?

Tags: android, arduino

I have an arduino which collects temperature data using DHT11, the data must be read on an android app using a wifi module (esp8266). How will i send the data of arduino to the android app? How will the android app receive the data from the wifi? Please help, any sample code for android app and arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a small webserver, either on the arduino or the ESP8266 itself. You can program the latter with the Arduino IDE as well and don't need the overhead of communication between the ESP8266 and the Arduino.

The project [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer) is a good start and has sample code available as well.

Access to the webserver is then simply made by a browser request. Any "Web-App" can use the same functionality.